# Powershell creating a Loop with more than one output txt

Tags: powershell

I cant find the solution , im very new to powershell so sorry for obvious mistakes.

```
$OU = (Get-Mailbox - OrganizationalUnit "HERE I PUT THE OU NAME".DistinguishedName 

$OU 
1..5 | foreach { Add-Content -Path .\Desktop\$_.txt}
```

But it says "Supply Values for the following parameters: Value [0]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a description of what you are trying to accomplish. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You want to output each of the objects in `$OU` to separate files named 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc.?

Comment: When you use the pipeline / foreach, it is not enough to call a cmdlet such as Add-Content `Add-Content` , you also need to indicate what you want to pass to it. In the case of `Add-Content`, it expect the `-Value` parameter to be passed down too so in your case, assuming you want to pass the content of each iteration of `$OU`, you need to do this `$OU 1..5 | foreach { Add-Content -Path .\Desktop$_.txt -Value $_}` ... If you are trying to pass only one property of `$OU` then you'll need to replace `-Value $_` and target the actual property (eg:`-Value $_.DistinguishedName`).

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors. PowerShell follows a unique, but simple, way of calling on cmdlets. You have the cmdlet name followed by whatever parameter and value (if it takes one); so it's cmdlet name space dash-parametername ( `Get-Mailbox -OranizationalUnit "org"`). In your case, you have an extra space in your parameter and are missing the closing of the *grouping* operator (*the parenthesis -`)`- *) . You also have your `$ou` variable in the same line as your pipeline to your `foreach` cmdlet. What is your overall intentions?

Comment: Plus `"HERE I PUT THE OU NAME"` is a **string** which doesn't have a property `.DistinguishedName`..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.